# Как реализовать алгоритм, необходимый для индексации AJAX-контента Яндексом

Tags: javascript, яндекс-поиск

Возникла проблема с контентом на сайте. У меня на странице 3 блока с информацией, которые подгружаются асинхронно посредством AJAX-запроса в Javascript. Google научил своих ботов исполнять JavaScript-код на сайтах и успешно индексирует весь ajax-контент. В документации же Яндекса сказано, что нужно предоставить браузеру html-версии страниц и указать на них посредством url-параметра `?_escaped_fragment`. А как это сделать? Ведь каждый отдельный блок генерируется отдельно друг от друга и я не знаю, когда страница загрузит весь свой контент и будет готова к использованию чтобы сделать её html-версию. Это нужно сделать на сервере, ведь таких страниц у меня около 21000.

Answer (score 1):

> Это нужно сделать на сервере, ведь таких страниц у меня около 21000.

Совершенно верно, это делается серверным скриптом, который генерирует страницу.
То есть, Вы просто сразу выводите на страницу тот контент, который возвращаете клиенту при AJAX-запросе. Например, если это комментарии подгружаемые постранично, то в HTML-версии документа выводите все комментарии сразу, одной простыней.

Общая форма записи на PHP выглядит примерно так:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_GET['_escaped_fragment_'])
    // опционально: проверка значения этой GET-переменной (если на странице несколько фрагментов динамического контента)
    // вывод статичной HTML-версии блока страницы
  else
    // вывод "обычной" AJAX-версии страницы, с подгрузкой контента блока на клиенте
?>
```

---

> Google научил своих ботов исполнять JavaScript-код на сайтах и успешно индексирует весь ajax-контент.

На самом деле, не совсем так :) Гуглоботы *пытаются* выполнять JavaScript-код, успешно ли - гарантии нет. И несмотря на то что официально гугл объявил `_escaped_fragment_` как deprecated, такие ссылки по-прежнему рекомендуют использовать, так как боты все еще используют этот AJAX crawling.

Comment: Ну у меня Google успешно проиндексировал весь контент, выводимый с помощью JS. Даже добавление скрипта json-ld на страницу.